# Two collections intersection

Tags: c#, collections, intersection

I am trying to intersect two collections. I've got two lists listed below in a code snippet.

This is my output:

```
Intersection
1
```

Why is only one value found? Is it the expected behavior or I am doing something wrong?

I expect my output looks like this:

```
Intersection
1
1
1
1
```

My code:

```
// Collection initialization
List<int> list1 = new List<int> { 1,1,1,1 }; 
List<int> list2 = new List<int> { 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 };

foreach (int q in list1)
    Console.WriteLine("list1: " + q);

Console.WriteLine("------------------");

foreach (int q in list2)
    Console.WriteLine("list2: " + q);

Console.WriteLine("------------------");
Console.WriteLine("Intersection");

IEnumerable<int> both = list1.Intersect(list2);

foreach (int a in both)
    Console.WriteLine(a);

Console.ReadLine();
Console.Clear();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx) makes your work more easier. Use `Contains` method like this:

```
List<int> resultList = list1.Where(c => list2.Contains(c)).ToList();
```

Just don't forget to add LINQ to your using directives first:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: This one worked exactly as I expected! Is it possible to do the same action but this time with DateTime?

Answer (score 4):

As you can read in the description of [Enumerable.Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The intersection of two sets A and B is defined as the set that
>   contains all the elements of A that also appear in B, but no other
>   elements.

In a [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) you only have distinct objects. So putting four 1s in a set is the same like putting it in only 1 time.
Thats why you get only one entry.

Answer (score 2):

Intersect return unique matching elements in both lists